# SSRS stored procedure speed

Tags: reporting-services

I have a simple SSRS report that generates QR codes based on two manually input parameter fields. No queries or data associated with the report.

When I run a stored procedure to execute the subscription, it takes 5-7 seconds. Therefore overwriting my parameters that I am passing using the stored procedure.

I am trying to print QR codes for pallets. Example I receive 3 pallets I want to print 3 pallet tags representing receiving ID-pallet.

```
501245-1
501245-2
501245-3
```

Right now if I don’t put and 7-8 second delay then I don’t get the right data coming out.

It will sometime either repeat or skip pallets.

Is there a flag I can wait until clears in one of the tables before going to the next one? Is there a way to speed up the pdf generation?

Comment: how do you generate your QR Codes? Can you do any performance tuning on the SP? Look at plans etc.. does the SP run within expected time frame on it's own?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are doing. FYI in the past I have implemented an SSRS report that accepts parameters, writes to the DB and returns a dataset _without_ using subscriptions.

Comment: We have production workstations throughout the plant/country.  When they finish a pallet on a job we want to print a pallet tag.     We built a ssrs report that has two basic parameters of job number and pallet number.

Comment: I mean it's not clear what you are doing in SSRS. How do subscriptions fit into this? If this is seriously impacting your supply chain I suggest you get someone to build you a quick web app to do this for you. I mean you probably don't even need to output as PDF to print a label.